# How to save the state of a checkbox with sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

How can I save the state of a check box to shared Preference and how can I retrieve its value from the shared preference when it is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Java file, Just do this:

```
public class Kul extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kul);

    final CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
    cb1.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("check", false));
    cb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(cb1.isChecked())
                {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
            settings.edit().putBoolean("check",true).commit();
         } else {
             SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
             settings.edit().putBoolean("check",false).commit();
        }
        }
    });
}
```

and it's done :-)

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like you might want to get familiar with Java Properties.

Take a look at this tutorial:[Java Properties Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

You can save key/values to a file, and then when your application starts up you can read the file. So this way you can save (to file) all your settings, and then later read the settings from the file.